# Notepad++ RegEx to remove text in brackets (including the brackets)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to remove the brackets and the text in between via find and replace funtion in Notpad++
Here is an example:

```
<span style="color: #00008b;">function</span> <span style="color: #8a2be2;">New-ISEMenu</span> <span style="color: #000000;">{</span>
```

should be regex'ed to:

```
function New-ISEMenu {
```

So basically < and > and everything in between should be removed.
Thanks for your help already!
Regards, Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regular expression mode

Find : `<[^>]*>`

Replace : `empty string` or

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mG8kZ9/4

Comment: I think the replacement should be a single space instead of an empty string, to avoid concatenating the left tokens.

Comment: That regex will not support something like `<tag property="something with >" >`.  Although this is not valid xml syntax, it is valid html, and as so, a proper regex would be: `<([^">']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>`  This allows secuences of double or single quoted delimited strings with embedded `<` or `>` characters.